# PostgreSQL: Run CTE and then Recursive query on the CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I am trying to run a recursive query in PostgreSQL. I need it to find all people that belong under a team. The query is the following:

```
WITH TAB AS (
SELECT id as user_id, team_id
from users

union

select user_id,team_id
from team_units
),
RECURSIVE recuree AS (
    SELECT user_id, team_id
    from TAB
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT E.user_id, E.team_id
    from TAB E
    JOIN recuree S on E.team_id = S.team_id)

SELECT * FROM recuree
```

I read that `RECURSIVE` must always followed from `WITH`.
But how can that happen since the `TAB` table doesn't actually exist?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: RECURSIVE **must** be the first part of the *chained* CTEs. (but you could *nest* them instead. Or use a VIEW)

Comment: Hello sir and thank you for your answer. I agree with you. Is there any workaround method to succesfully run this?

Comment: @LaSanton: yes, move the `recursive` keyword right after the `WITH`

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the CREATE function since I am permitted just to execute query. What you mean by saying nest?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that I tried that and nothing different comes as result.

Comment: So what is the error you get in that case?

Comment: I don't get any error sir but the results are the same as without recursive query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use `WITH RECURSIVE`, so you can try to use a subquery to instead `TAB`

`RECURSIVE` need to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

```
WITH RECURSIVE recuree AS (
    SELECT user_id, team_id
    from (
        SELECT id as user_id, team_id
        from users
        union
        select user_id,team_id
        from team_units
    ) t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT E.user_id, E.team_id
    from (
        SELECT id as user_id, team_id
        from users
        union
        select user_id,team_id
        from team_units
    ) E
    JOIN recuree S on E.team_id = S.team_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM recuree
```

otherwise, you can try to create a view first

```
CREATE VIEW v_TAB AS 
SELECT id as user_id, team_id
from users
union
select user_id,team_id
from team_units;
```

then do CTE `RECURSIVE`

```
WITH RECURSIVE recuree AS (
    SELECT user_id, team_id
    from v_TAB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT E.user_id, E.team_id
    from v_TAB E
    JOIN recuree S on E.team_id = S.team_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM recuree;
```

Comment: The 1st query is the one that works for me. I couldn't think that i can actually retrieve it from nested query. Thank you so much sir! Please upvote the question if you believe it can help others.

Comment: @LaSanton The duplication of the "tab" query isn't necessary. [This](https://pastebin.com/A38W0yCx) should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That works sir! It wasn't working because the ALL is missing next to UNION. Thank you!Please upvote the question if you believe it can help others.